# Flash microbit embedding a class .py file

Tags: micropython, bbc-microbit, flashing

Using `BBC micro:bit` with the `scroll:bit` pimoroni extension device, I need to embed the `scrollbit.py` file in my HEX file.

I use my favorite editor to produce my python file and `uFlash` to flash the micro:bit.
For now I just copy the code from inside the `scrollbit.py` into my own python script. Is there any alternative without using Mu editor ?

**Edit** I found `microfs` and the `ufs` line command, I had to change my python script in `main.py` and transfer it to the microbit using :

```
ufs put scrollbit.py
ufs put main.py
```

Comment: If you found the answer to your own question you can post it as an answer and accept it.

Comment: You're correct to use `ufs put scroll.py` but you could still use `uflash` to flash the microbit. Flash the microbit first, it will display an import error. Just use `ufs` then. The disadvantage with this is you need to `ufs put scroll.py` each time you flash the microbit

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for late but I encounter the same issue and want to make things more clear

You could also use this to flash ur renamed main script into microbit
`ufs put YourMainScript.py main.py`
This automatically upload YourMainScript.py and rename it to main.py in microbit

And then upload other python library with
`ufs put scrollbit.py`

Which you dont need uflash at all and because it doesn't require converting python script into hex file, its even faster.