# How do I transfer my Python script including my module to the micro:bit?

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, micropython, bbc-microbit, flashing

We use the micro:bit with the accessory Bit:bot XL. I have a module (robot.py) with just a single function for the Bit:bot (for now). In my script (my.py) I import this function. But after flashing the micro:bit (uflash my.py), there's an error on the LED matrix saying: "Import error: No module named robot". However, if I just use standard Python functions (like print()) in my module and run my script in the VSCode terminal, it works fine. Putting my function directly into my script also works fine. Why can't I transfer both my script and my module to the micro:bit?

A workaround can be found at [Flash microbit embedding a class .py file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52782520/flash-microbit-embedding-a-class-py-file?r=SearchResults&s=1|256.7628). The workaround requires you to flash the micro:bit first and then transfer modules with ufs. It works, but makes things more complicated for our target group which is blind children.

My module robot.py is stored in a folder called bitbot. The folder path is specified in sys.path. In the package there is also an empty file `__init__.py`.

```
# my.py
from microbit import *
from robot import drive

drive(500, 3000)
```

```
# bitbot/robot.py
from microbit import *

def drive(speed, duration):
    """Makes the Bit:bot move forwards with a given speed for a number of milliseconds"""
    pin8.write_digital(0) #Left motor direction
    pin12.write_digital(0) #Right motor direction
    pin16.write_analog(speed) #Left motor speed
    pin14.write_analog(speed) #Right motor speed
    sleep(duration)
```

I have tried different ways to import the module but they all give the same import error:
import bitbot, import robot, from bitbot import *, from robot import *, from bitbot import drive, from robot import drive, from bitbot.robot import drive.

I use:

- Python 3.7
- VSCode 1.42.1
- VSCode Python extension https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python
- VSCode micro:bit extension https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=PhonicCanine.micro-bit
- 4tronix Bit:bot XL v. 1.0 (the pin configuration differs from that of the Bit:bot v. 1.3)

Comment: Have you looked at either [Mu](https://codewith.mu/en/) or [Thonny](https://thonny.org/) as an alternative IDE? They both provide an interface for copying library files etc to the micro:bit ([Mu's](https://codewith.mu/en/howto/1.0/copy_files_microbit), [Thonny's](https://github.com/thonny/thonny/wiki/MicroPython).) Obviously they are both a lot simpler than VS Code but that might be more appropriate for your target users - unless there's some accessibility-related reason for using VS Code.

Comment: Mu doesn't work well with screen readers. I have not tested Thonny, but there seems to some accessibility issues even there: [link](https://github.com/thonny/thonny/issues/949). VSCode might not be the simplest editor, but the great accessibility support makes it easy to use after all.

Answer (score 0):

You will likely need to install a VSCode extension to write the files to your MicroBit. Have a look at [micro:bit by Joseph Fergusson](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=PhonicCanine.micro-bit)